# RegisterArrayDeclaration in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I m trying to Register a Array in CodeBehind(C#) in PageLaod()

```
Page_Load()

{

           System.Text.StringBuilder sbScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sbScript.Append(",");
            sbScript.Append("abc");
            sbScript.Append(",");
            sbScript.Append("xyz");

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("checkBoxes", sbScript.ToString());

}

When i see the Source View of the Page :

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var checkBoxes =  new Array(,abc,xyz);
//]]>
</script>


When i try to access the array in some JS function :

function lookupValue()
    {
      alert('There are ' + checkBoxes.length + 'checkboxes');

}
```

it throws an error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'checkBoxes' is undefined.

I m working with MasterPages . Pls assist me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript array value is starting with a comma, which raises a syntax error. It also generates unquoted strings:

```
var checkBoxes =  new Array(,abc,xyz);  // Invalid syntax.
```

You probably should write:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sbScript.Append("'abc'");
sbScript.Append(", ");
sbScript.Append("'xyz'");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("checkBoxes", sbScript.ToString());
```

Which will give:

```
var checkBoxes =  new Array('abc', 'xyz');  // Okay.
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But my Problem is when i try to access the array in some function in javascript file (.js) its giving error stating :"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'checkBoxes' is undefined" Is that becz of Master Pages, which i m using or becz of using .js file separately  (I m able to see <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var checkBoxes =  new Array('cba','abc','xyz');
//]]>
</script> , in the View Source but not able to accees). Kindly help me out

Comment: @Basavaraj, maybe the script that uses the array runs before the array is defined? Can you check the script ordering in the page source?